# Flink Scheduling Strategy

Tags: apache-flink

I know the Flink Default Scheduler strategy,but I want to change the startegy in 
some situations.For example,Io intensive and Cpu intensive,I want to change default  when the cluster resource has great difference in every node.So if I can do My startegy based the cluster resource?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not easily possible. The community is, however, working on making Flink's [scheduling component pluggable](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10429). With this change, it will be possible to provide your own `Scheduler` implementation which gives you fine grained control over Flink's scheduling logic.

Moreover, the community also works on enabling `ResourceSpecs` which will allow you specify the resource requirements of a specific operator. Flink will then make sure that it assigns a slot with at least as many resources to the operator as specified.